# Import a matrix in c

Tags: c

Hello I am trying to import a metric to from a text file. Initially I know nothing about the matrix so I calculate the number of lines in the matrix and then allocate space to it. When I am trying to import the matrix I run into an infinite loop. I do not get why

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i,j;
    char ch;
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        puts ( "Cannot open source file");
    }

    /*count the number of lines*/
    int lines=1;
    char c,junk;
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == '\n')
            lines++;
    }
    printf("lines= %i\n",lines);

    double matrix[lines][100];
    for(i = 0 ; i < lines ; i++)
    {
        j = 0;
        do{
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &matrix[lines][j]);
            j++;
        }while((junk = fgetc(fp)) != '\n');
    }
}
```

Matrix in text file:

```
   0.5000    0.4600    0.6400    0.3600    0.5000         0    0.4900    0.2200    1
    0.5300    0.5600    0.4900    0.4600    0.5000         0    0.5200    0.2200    1
    0.5200    0.5300    0.5800    0.6900    0.5000         0    0.5000    0.2200    1
    0.6700    0.6200    0.5400    0.4300    0.5000         0    0.5300    0.2200    1
    0.4500    0.5700    0.3000    0.1700    0.5000         0    0.5100    0.2200    3
    0.6800    0.5300    0.4400    0.3100    0.5000         0    0.5100    0.2200    1
    0.3800    0.4200    0.3100    0.3500    0.5000         0    0.5200    0.2200    3
    0.4800    0.4600    0.5800    0.2600    0.5000         0    0.4400    0.2200    2
    0.4500    0.3900    0.4600    0.2900    0.5000         0    0.4200    0.2200    1
    0.7800    0.7500    0.4000    0.2800    0.5000         0    0.5300    0.2200    1
    0.7400    0.8900    0.3200    0.2400    0.5000         0    0.5400    0.3200    4
    0.2100    0.4100    0.5500    0.1100    0.5000         0    0.5000    0.2700    7
    0.3500    0.5600    0.3600    0.3000    0.5000         0    0.5300    0.2500    3
    0.8000    0.7300    0.4700    0.1900    0.5000         0    0.4900    0.2200    4
    0.7600    0.7600    0.3500    0.2700    0.5000         0    0.4400    0.2200    4
    0.3800    0.4000    0.5300    0.1200    0.5000         0    0.5500    0.2200    7
    0.6500    0.6300    0.4700    0.2200    0.5000         0    0.5200    0.2700    7
    0.4100    0.4900    0.5500    0.1300    0.5000         0    0.5500    0.2200    7
    0.5300    0.5100    0.5100    0.1100    0.5000         0    0.4900    0.4100    2
    0.8500    0.8500    0.3000    0.3100    0.5000         0    0.5500    0.4200    4
    0.6100    0.4800    0.5600    0.1900    0.5000         0    0.5300    0.3100    7
    0.5500    0.6900    0.5100    0.1200    0.5000         0    0.5100    0.2200    7
    0.4900    0.4000    0.5800    0.2300    0.5000         0    0.4700    0.2700    7
    0.5600    0.5700    0.6300    0.3900    1         0    0.5900    0.4000    2
    0.4500    0.5000    0.5700    0.2900    0.5000         0    0.4400    0.1100    7
    0.3200    0.4400    0.5400    0.2100    0.5000         0    0.4000    0.1900    7
    0.7500    0.6700    0.5100    0.2900    0.5000         0    0.5200    0.3600    1
    0.6300    0.5400    0.5300    0.2700    0.5000         0    0.4900    0.2200    7
```

Comment: You need to change to `int c`. A `char` may not be able to hold `EOF`, but `int` will.

Comment: ok. Also how do I import the data using my program. When I try to import that data it goes to an infinite loop.

Comment: `while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)` that will read the whole file and leave `fp` pointing to the end of the file. So there is nothing for the subsequent `fscanf` to read. Call `rewind` to get back to the beginning of the file. And suggest you don't mix `fscanf` and `fgetc`...that's just a recipe for disaster as they will interfere with each other unless you are very careful.

Comment: so how do I make sure it goes to the next line while also importing the matrix in the correct way? Sorry for all the trouble I am new to programming and this is kinda confusing for me

Comment: I told you in the other question you asked. Use `fgets` to read a whole line into a buffer as a string. Then `sscanf` on that string to parse the float values.

Comment: that maybe true if we know the number of columns what do I do when I do not know that?

Comment: That's a seperate issue. You already have code that counts the number of lines. That's not the way I would do it but it's ok and I did not say you need to remove it. I just said you need to `rewind` before trying to read the data after counting the lines. Then the next block that reads the data should not use fscanf+fgetc. It should use `fgets+sscanf`.

Comment: can you write that function in code because I am not able to figure out how I can make it work with a matrix with n rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fgets()` to read entire lines, and then use `sscanf()` when you know the format of the individual lines. In this case, the number of entries per line is unknown, so `strtok()` can be used to split each line into tokens. The number of tokens on each line can be counted, and if this varies, a warning can be printed, or other error handling.

This code is not perfect, but it adapts what you had to make it work. The `atof()` function is used to parse a string token into a `double` value. It would be better to use `strtod()` for this purpose as it allows for error-checking, but `atof()` is simpler to use, and so is used here.

The original code had `c` as a `char`, but it should be an `int`, since it is expected to hold `EOF`. Also, after the first pass through the file to count the number of lines, `fp` must be reset to the beginning of the file with `rewind(fp)`. I also added some code to display the contents of `matrix` at the end of the program.

Here is the modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i,j;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        puts ( "Cannot open source file");
    }

    /*count the number of lines*/
    int c, lines=1;                 // changed c to int
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == '\n')
            lines++;
    }
    printf("lines= %i\n",lines);

    rewind(fp);                     // back to start of file

    /* Read file in a line at a time */
    char buffer[1000];
    char *token;
    double matrix[lines][100];
    int columns = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL) {
        j = 0;
        /* Parse each line with strtok() and atof() */
        token = strtok(buffer, " \n");
        while (token) {
            matrix[i][j] = atof(token);
            ++j;
            token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }
        if (columns == 0) {
            columns = j;
        } else if (columns != j) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Inconsistent column dimension in row %d\n", i);
        }
        ++i;
    }

    /* Display results */
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            printf("%8.5g", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```